# How to batch insert when insert depends on data ready to be batched

Tags: java, sql, database, architecture, derby

My Java application reads rows from a CSV file and puts them into a database (Apache Derby). I want to implement batch inserts because I am inserting thousands of records, so I'd like a performance improvement. However, how the data is inserted depends on the data that is already in the database e.g. I want to batch the following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES (?);
```

But then, I only perform the above if the below does not return any data:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='Tim';
```

If I am batching inserts, then my SELECT may not find the most recent data because it is waiting to be batched.

Can anyone identify a solution? Maybe a caching mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would be to make your batch entries INSERT/SELECT statements, such that inserts will only happen if the query's condition is satisfied.

That will be something like:

```
Lists<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
//.... data in list assumed
for(String username: usernames) {
    statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO USER(NAME) SELECT '" + username+ "' FROM USER WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM USER WHERE NAME = '" + username + "')");
}
```

This will get the database to deal with checking whether the record being inserted exists or not.
Each statement for which a corresponding is already in the database will simply not insert and the return count for it will be 0. But you wouldn't care about it anyway.

I quickly googled and saw that Derby apparently support the INSERT/SELECT feature. You can find more about this syntax here: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj40.html